# How to use "setTimeout" to invoke object itself

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Why can't I use `setTimeout` in a javascript object?

```
Message = function () {

    ...
    ...        

    this.messageFactory = ...
    this.feedbackTag = document.getElementById('feedbackMessages');

    this.addInfo = function (message) {
        var info = this.messageFactory.createInfo(message); // create a div
        this.feedbackTag.appendChild(info);

        setTimeout('this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info)', 5000);
        // why in here, it complain this.feedbacktag is undefined ??????

    };
}
```

Thanks for Steve`s Solution, now it will work if the code is as below...
because the 'this' before was actually pointing to the function within setTimeOut, it cannot rearch Message.

```
Message = function () {

    ...
    ...        

    this.messageFactory = ...
    this.feedbackTag = document.getElementById('feedbackMessages');

    this.addInfo = function (message) {
        var info = this.messageFactory.createInfo(message); // create a div
        this.feedbackTag.appendChild(info);

        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() { _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info); }, 5000);

    };
}
```

But why doesn`t it work if we do this:

```
Message = function () {

    ...
    ...        

    this.messageFactory = ...
    this.feedbackTag = document.getElementById('feedbackMessages');
    // public function
    this.addInfo = function (message) {
        var info = this.messageFactory.createInfo(message); // create a div
        this.feedbackTag.appendChild(info);

        delayRemove(info);

    };
    // private function
    function delayRemove(obj) {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() { _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info); }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Comment: Duplicates: [setTimeout() inside JavaScript Class using “this”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this) and [Using setTimeout() within a JavaScript class function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997921/using-settimeout-within-a-javascript-class-function)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
setTimeout('this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info)', 5000);
```

with these two lines:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() { _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info); }, 5000);
```

**Note:**

Never pass [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) a string, as this invokes `eval` (which you should only use when necessary). Instead, pass [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) a function reference (this can be an anonymous function).

Finally, always check that the `this` keyword is pointing to what you think it points to (see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations).

**Addressing Question 2:**

I believe that for normal functions, `this` is set to the `window` object—regardless of where they are declared. So moving the code into a separate function wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that introduce a memory leak?

Comment: @shrimpy: It's a complex problem, but this article describes it quite well: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations. Basically, "this" doesn't point to the Message class inside the anonymous function. To fix this problem, we create a variable (I called it "_this"), make it point to the correct Message class, and then use this variable when we want to reference the class inside the anonymous function.

Comment: @tslib: In what way? This workaround is quite common. If you're worried that the anonymous function is going to keep things tied up, I'm pretty sure that it will be zapped by the Garbage Collector as soon as "setTimeout" has finished with it.

Comment: @tsilb: Whoops—I spelt your username incorrectly in my previous comment! Sorry!

Comment: Wonderful solution. Never knew you could pass an anon function!

Comment: I think it's because setTimeout is a Window method, when it calls the callback anonymous function, 'this' refers to the window object. Since setTimeout is a method from window, the anonymous function receive 'this' as the context being Window object.

Comment: Surprising, nobody used the word *closure* yet ... ;-)

Comment: Maybe because there isn't any _closure_ in the example? ;)

Comment: There *is* a closure, as the anonymous function accesses the `_this` variable, which is outside of its own immediate lexical scope.

Answer (score 9):

A neater way is to just pass *this* as an argument to the function being called in the timeout:

```
function delayRemove(obj) {
  setTimeout(function(_this) {
      _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(obj);
    }, 5000, this);
}
```

You should really pass *obj* as an argument as well, just to make sure it is in scope (the number of parameters is unlimited):

```
function delayRemove(obj) {
  setTimeout(function(_this, removeObj) {
      _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(removeObj);
    }, 5000, this, obj);
}
```

---

HTML5 and Node.js extended the `setTimeout` function to accept parameters which are passed to your callback function. It has the following method signature.

`setTimeout(callback, delay, [param1, param2, ...])`

As `setTimeout` [isn't actually a JavaScript feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852244/155715) your results may vary across browsers. I couldn't find any concrete details of support, however as I said this is in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: all browsers now support the third parameter of setTimeout?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question:  "Why doesn`t it work if we do this":

```
Message = function () {

...
...        

this.messageFactory = ...
this.feedbackTag = document.getElementById('feedbackMessages');
// public function
this.addInfo = function (message) {
    var info = this.messageFactory.createInfo(message); // create a div
    this.feedbackTag.appendChild(info);

    delayRemove(info);

};
// private function
function delayRemove(obj) {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() { _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(info); }, 5000);
}}
```

It's not working because you are passing an undefined variable (`info`) instead of a defined variable (`obj`). Here is the corrected function:

```
function delayRemove(obj) {
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() { _this.feedbackTag.removeChild(obj); }, 5000);}
```