# setTimeout() inside JavaScript Class using "this"

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I am trying to use `setTimeout()` inside a class function in JavaScript. The `setTimeout()` is supposed to trigger another method in the same Class, so the function I am passing it is written as `window.setTimeout("this.anotherMethod", 4000)`. That bring the problem: `this` references the calling Object, in the case of `setTimeout()` it is `window`. How can I use enclosures to return a reference to the Class Object itself?

```
myObject = function(){

this.move = function(){
    alert(this + " is running");
}
this.turn = function(){
    alert(this + " is turning");
}
this.wait = function(){
    window.setTimeout("this.run" ,(1000 * randomNumber(1,5)));
}

this.run = function(){
    switch(randomNumber(0,2)){
        case 0:
            this.move();
        break;
        case 1:
            this.turn();
        break;
        case 2:
            this.wait();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I set that = this, and used that for all the methods, works like magic, +1 for everyone who answered that, thanks a lot folks.

Comment: Easy way, use this syntax: `methodName = () => {}`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 var that = this;
 setTimeout(function () {
     that.doStuff();
 }, 4000);
```

You can also [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more succinct code (as originally pointed out by @Raynos):

```
setTimeout(this.doStuff.bind(this), 4000);
```

`bind` is a standard library function for exactly this coding pattern (ie capturing `this` lexically).

Comment: @David Dorward: I realized that just after hitting submit. I shouldn't post at 5 in the morning.

Comment: @Dorward commented before the answer was edited. Now is correct

Comment: I used this answer in a class with a singleton pattern implemented an it works!

Comment: I find the syntax of @Raynos answer much cleaner (see below). ES 5 .bind() precisely solves this problem.

Comment: @Antoine: Fair enough, and ES5 support is probably widespread enough by now that using it is a complete non-issue. I'll edit in a note about that.

Comment: what does the syntax look like for passing parameters to doStuff? setTimeout(this.doStuff.bind(this), 4000, param);

Comment: `bind` can take the additional arguments: `setTimeout(this.doStuff.bind(this, param), 4000)`.

Comment: Is it just me or do I find this hilarious? Good answer though!

Answer (score 14):

You can also bind a function to scope.

`setTimeout(this.run.bind(this) ,(1000 * randomNumber(1,5)));`

Be warned `Function.prototype.bind` is ES5

Comment: you can just get bind to work on any js project: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind :)

Answer (score 8):

`this` can be problematic in javascript, as you've discovered.

I usually work around this by aliasing `this` inside the object so that I can use the alias whenever I need a reference back to the containing object.

```
MyObject = function ()
{
    var self = this;

    // The rest of the code goes here

    self.wait = function(){
        window.setTimeout(self.run ,(1000 * randomNumber(1,5)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I find `self` to be a most misleading identifier, not least because it has very similar connotations to `this` which, as you point out, means something else.

Comment: Well it is just an example, you could call it MyObjRef, or anything else you think it should be.  The point is that it gives you a way of getting the object reference.

Answer (score 5):

```
class A{

   setTimeout(()=>{

       // here this != undefined because of arrow function

  },500);

}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
this.wait = function(){
    var self = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() { self.run() } ,(1000 * randomNumber(1,5)));
}
```

So you store the reference to the object you're calling .run on in a local variable ('self').

Answer (score 3):

`this` is sensitive to the context in which it is called. When you pass a string to `setTimeout` then that is `eval`ed in a completely different context.

You need to preserve the current value of `this` (by copying it to a different variable) and maintain the scope (by not using (implied) `eval`).

```
this.wait = function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () { self.run() },
              (1000 * randomNumber(1,5))
              );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your main `myObject` make a new reference to the current value of `this`:

```
var self = this;
```

and then create a closure for your timer callback that uses that new reference instead of the global object that `setTimeout` will use as the default context in callbacks:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    self.run();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

inside `func`, `this` always refer to the global object. you can pass in the current object into func,

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, this);
function func(that) {...}
```

unfortunately it does NOT work in IE

[Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 2):

you can just use the arrow function syntax:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
     this.doStuff();
 }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried;

```
window.setTimeout("myObject.run" ,(1000 * randomNumber(1,5)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead, which works in all modern browsers -

```
setTimeout(function(thisObj) {thisObj.run();},1000,this);
```

Ref: http://klevo.sk/javascript/javascripts-settimeout-and-how-to-use-it-with-your-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way. Without anonymous func.

```
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(self.method, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use setTimeout or setInterval using strings

```
setTimeout("myFunction()", 5000);

//this is the same as 

setTimeout(function(){ eval("myFunction()"); }, 5000)); //<-- eval == BAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a more complex situation...class A has a member of type B and a method that calls setTimeout which calls a method on class B. Solved as follows:

```
class A {
    constructor(b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    setTimer(interval) {
        setTimeout(this.b.tick.bind(this.b), interval);
    }
}
class B {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.ele = window.document.getElementById('B');
    }
    tick() {
        console.log(this);
        this.ele.innerText += ' ' + this.name;
    }
}
```

Which bound A.b to this within B.tick and worked.

Here's a fiddle with `bind`: https://jsfiddle.net/jrme9hyh/

And one without `bind` which fails: https://jsfiddle.net/2jde8tq3/