# how to use recursive setTimeout from within a method

Tags: javascript, prototype, settimeout

Im trying to use setTimeout() for a recursive function, inside a method. I'm assuming I'm getting something with the 'this' scope wrong though. Here's an example.

```
(function(scope){
    function gamePlay(){
       // this.initialize();
    }

    gamePlay.prototype.droidMovement = function(){
        console.log('droid is moving');
        this.droidShoot();
    }    

    gamePlay.prototype.droidShoot = function(){
        console.log('droidShoot() has been fired');
        setTimeout(this.droidShoot,1000);
    }   

scope.gamePlay = gamePlay;    
})(window);

var game = new gamePlay();
game.droidMovement();
```

Ive tried the setTimeout 3 ways.

```
//this way repeats the function 2 times then stops
setTimeout(this.droidShoot,1000);

//this gives me an error
setTimeout(function(){this.droidShoot()},1000);

//this fires the function in a loop but doesnt wait the second
setTimeout(this.droidShoot(),1000);
```

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong? thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to remove the `setTimeout` from within the definition of `droidShoot` and replace `setTimeout(this.droidShoot, 1000)` with `setInterval(this.droidShoot, 1000`.

setInterval will automatically call `this.droidShoot` repeatedly at a 1s interval

Comment: thanks Jason. I just found an answer allowing for the use of setTimeout.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this