# Why does this class attribute come out as undefined even though it was defined?

Tags: javascript, timer

**Explanation**

I am writing a program to measure reaction time, and I have this class that I'm trying to create that measures the time taken to react. After calling the startDelayTimer() which is when the "start" button in my program would be pressed, it creates a random delay from 1 to 4 seconds, and then the screen turns green and you have to press the spacebar when it turns green. The problem is, the first console.log() in *calculateDelayTime()* outputs *undefined* as the value of this.timeElapsed. In *startDelayTimer()*, this.timeElapsed is still 0. I'm not sure why it is undefined.  Any advice?

**Code**

```
class ReactionTimer {
    constructor() {
        this.timeTotal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301) * 10;
        this.timeElapsed = 0;
    }
    startDelayTimer() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.calculateDelayTime, 10);
    }
    calculateDelayTime() {
        console.log(this.timeElapsed);
        this.timeElapsed += 10;
        if (this.timeElapsed >= this.timeTotal) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            document.querySelector(".rectangle").style.backgroundColor =
                "green";
            this.timeElapsed = 0;
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                this.timeElapsed += 1;
            }, 1);
            document.onkeydown = () => {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                document.onkeydown = null;
                console.log(this.timeElapsed);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we test that ? did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout() inside JavaScript Class using "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this) or [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Also relevant [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) | [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)

Comment: @Ivar Thanks! I guess behaviour of this works differently inside callbacks. Used .bind(this) and it was fixed.