# Javascript Timeout Issue

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript class:

```
function PageManager () {
    this.timeoutHandler = function () {
        alert ("hello");
    }

    this.startTimeout = function () {
        this.timeout = setTimeout ("this.timeoutHandler()", 1000);
    }
}
```

When I call `obj.startTimeout ();` I get this error:

```
this.timeoutHandler is not a function
```

How do I call a class function in the timeout?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101668/javascript-howto-use-settimeout-to-invoked-obecjt-itself

Comment: `obj` isn't the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass a string to `setTimeout`, the code is evaluated in the **global scope**. Always pass a **function reference**:

```
this.startTimeout = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       self.timeoutHandler();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or if you don't need a reference to the object inside `timeoutHandler`, then you can pass the function directly:

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(this.timeoutHandler, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing `setTimeout` a string.  This string is `eval`'d, with a scope of the window.  So if you were to do this:

```
    this.timeout = setTimeout ("console.log(this);", 1000);
```

... with Firebug installed, you'd see that `this` is `window`, which does not have a `timeoutHandler` method, of course.

This is why you should never, ever pass `setTimeout` a string.  Give it a function reference instead.

```
function PageManager () {
    this.timeoutHandler = function () {
        alert ("hello");
         console.log(this);
    }

    this.startTimeout = function () {
        this.timeout = setTimeout (this.timeoutHandler, 1000);
    }
}
obj = new PageManager ();
obj.startTimeout();
```

When you execute this code, you'll have the scope you're expecing.