# Why is an anonymous function required to preserve "this" using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I've used `setTimeout` plenty of times passing a function as a reference e.g.

```
setTimeout(someFunction, 3000);
```

In some cases, to preserve the value of `this` I've had to assign it to a variable before hand, but don't understand why the following does not work:

```
var logger = {
    log: function() { 
        var that = this;
        console.log(that.msg); 
        setTimeout(that.log, 3000); 
    },
    msg: "test"
};

logger.log();
```

Using an anonymous function however, does work:

```
var logger = {
    log: function() { 
        var that = this;
        console.log(that.msg); 
        setTimeout(function() { that.log() }, 3000); 
    },
    msg: "test"
};
```

Comment: [The "this" problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem): _Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global) object; it will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout._

Comment: Not sure if it's an exact dupe, but seems to be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101668/how-to-use-settimeout-to-invoke-object-itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work as `setTimeout` calls a function with the `this` value as the global object, not the parent object. You're passing a value into the `setTimeout` function -- it doesn't know how it's been accessed, and therefore cannot call it with the correct `this` value (unlike normal variables, the value of `this` is only determined when you call the function, unless `this` has been bound to a specific value using `Function.prototype.bind`).

By changing that to an anonymous function, you're using the closure to access the value of `that`, even when called as a value (the variable scope of a function is set when it is defined, not when it is run).

It's just like if you do something like this:

```
var a = { b: function () { return this.foo; }, foo: 'proper' };
function test(arg) {
    return arg();
}
var foo = 'random';
console.log(a.b()); // proper
console.log(test(a.b)); // random
```

There's also a related question on using `this` with `setTimeout`: [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first case you reference only the function `log` that is within the `that` object, but its relationship to `that` is lost. Think of it as `setTimeout` calls directly the `log` method at the stored memory address with the global context.

In the second example however you come from a global context, but first `that` is looked up, and afterwards `log` which is called then with the context of `that`.

Think of setTimeout having the following structure:

```
var setTimeout = function (func, time) {
   someWaitMechanism(time, function () { //this is called after the timeout
       func.call(null); //calls func with global scope
   });
}
```

Comment: `func.call(null)` and `func()` would be no different, right? You might want to make that clear ;)

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize that the `thisArg` is set to `null`, therefore global context, but you are right :)

Comment: Indeed, that might not be that obvious :)